# Azure AD B2B Import in new portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm just looking for a yes or no answer here, and I can't seem to find anything online...

Can I upload B2B users into Azure AD using the new portal (i.e. The resource manager approach - portal.azure.com), or do I have to continue using the classic portal (manage.windowsazure.com)?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-what-is-azure-ad-b2b.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now add guest users via the new portal, although it's on a one-by-one basis, if you want to do it in bulk you can with a new PowerShell command.

```
New-AzureADMSInvitation
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azuread/v2/new-azureadmsinvitation

And a sample here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-code-samples.md#powershell-example

You'll need this package: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.0.38

Comment: So there is no longer a distinction between a B2B user and a guest user?

Comment: Yes there is, a B2B user will be userType = Guest, others are of type Member. An admin can change a Guest to a Member.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this feature is not support for the new portal. And if you want to the new portal to support this feature, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: The active directory feature in new portal is still in preview. Just wait it out.