# Not able Add the B2B invitation in Azure new portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Currently we are working on Azure SSO migration project and doing most of the task using old azure site. we have received a mail from the Microsoft via Client to use the new azure portal.
To provide the access for B2B, in old portal we straight uploaded the files with application id and the group id and that worked well.
But, in new portal when the did the same, the ids' are getting created in azure AD portal but they are not mapped in the groups that we have created for B2B invitation for the application.

Is there any approach is there. please help.

Regards,

Avisekh

Comment: Also I have found one answer for the above though not yet tried:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509848/azure-ad-b2b-import-in-new-portal?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The feature in the Azure Portal allows you to add individual requests by adding guest accounts, but if you need to invite multiple people or have any type of automation, you should:

- Use [PowerShell `New-AzureADMSInvitation` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-api#powershell)

[or]

- Use the [Microsoft Graph API invitations](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/invitation_post)

If you need to add users to groups, then you can also use the [Dynamic Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-dynamic-groups) feature in Azure B2B (perhaps this is more similar to what you used to have), as well as [Graph API Groups API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_members) or via PowerShell.